# Astro.js is not correctly importing functions

Tags: import, export, astrojs

I am brand new to Astro.js. I've tried several ways to import a "global" function on another page but I always get an error saying the function "is not defined". Here is my code from the master/global layout page...

```
export function test1() {
    console.log('test1()');
}
```

And here is the code on a separate page...

```
import test1 from '../layouts/master.astro';
```

(later on that same page...)

```
setTimeout(() => {
    test1();
}, 100);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Ah I figured it out. I updated the master page with the following code...

```
<script is:inline src="/global-methods.js"></script>
<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        main();
    }, 100);
</script>
```

("global-methods.js" is in the public directory.)
After doing that, I was able to reference my methods in subsequent pages.

Comment: Great discovery. Having to load an external file to have typed global functions is a shame though.

Comment: I wonder how to do that with a TypeScript file...